# firefox error in eclips during compile of html5

Tags: ajax, eclipse

hi last day i installed a ajax tool in my eclipse for js and html page editor and to debug them, but unfortunately it stop working, my project doesn't show any output and before i installed ajax tool output was executed in chrome and now it opens in Firefox  please can anyone help me thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please be more clear about your problem .what errors are you getting ?

Comment: when i run my html page it display error box with : error opening mozilla browser...editor part didnot initialize properly

Comment: I am not aware of this error, it seems to be a issue with the browser.vTry to open it with chrome, go to preferences in eclipse menu tab, search for browsers in the search pane and select the browser option,click add external browser, browse for chrome shortcut or exe and add it, check the chrome option and click ok and run now.

Comment: no its not working k how can i uninstall the ajax from eclipse that may work because before i installed the ajax tool my project worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your installation was proper , Make a proper installation including mozilla features :-

1) Press Help -> Install New Software...

2) Tell Eclipse the source of Mozilla features. Mozilla features provides pieces to embed standard Mozilla browser inside Eclipse.

In "Work with" field, paste following URL and press Enter: http://beta.zend.com/studio-eclipse/updates-extra/9_0 .
This repository will be needed later, so don't select anything from here for now.

3) Install Ajax Tools Framework. They integrate Mozilla browser with Eclipse frameworks to let you inspect, analyze and debug extra information, that is not available in typical Mozilla-based browsers.

In "Work with" field, paste following URL and press Enter: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/atf/updates/0.3.0
After a second, you should see available software.
Choose all items.
Make sure that option "Contact all update sites..." is checked.
Press "Next" and "Finish" and wait until Eclipse downloads and installs all selected items. You will be asked to restart Eclipse.

4)After restarting, to start working with your new software, switch to Web Browser Tools perspective

To uninstall the current software extension or plugin from eclipse refer this :-
http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_remove_a_plug-in%3F